# Pulling data while pivoting at the same time

Tags: sql, oracle, sybase

```
   ID | Type     | Code
   1    Purchase   A1
   1    Return     B1
   1    Exchange   C1
   2    Purchase   D1
   2    Return     NULL
   2    Exchange   F1
   3    Purchase   G1
   3    Return     H1
   3    Exchange   I1
   4    Purchase   J1
   4    Exchange   K1
```

Above is sample data. What I want to return is:

```
ID | Type     | Code
 1    Purchase   A1
 1    Return     B1
 1    Exchange   C1
 3    Purchase   G1
 3    Return     H1
 3    Exchange   I1
```

So if a field is null in code or the values of Purchase, Return and Exchange are not all present for that ID, ignore that ID completely. However there is one last step. I want this data to then be pivoted this way:

```
ID | Purchase | Return | Exchange
1    A1         B1       C1
3    G1         H1       I1
```

I asked this yesterday without the pivot portion which you can see here:

[SQL query to return data only if ALL necessary columns are present and not NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41450804/sql-query-to-return-data-only-if-all-necessary-columns-are-present-and-not-null)

However I forgot to note the last part. I tried to play around with excel but had no luck. I tried to make a temp table but the data is too large to do that so I was wondering if this could all be done in 1 sql statement?

I personally used this query with success:

```
select t.*
from t
where 3 = (select count(distinct t2.type)
       from t t2
       where t2.id = t.id and
             t2.type in ('Purchase', 'Exchange', 'Return') and
             t2.Code is not null
      );
```

So how can we adjust that to include the pivot part. Is that possible?

Comment: There is a huge difference between Oracle and Sybase. Which one are you really using?

Comment: It's complicated but lets say Sybase but the below answers worked

Comment: Is it possible in your data to have multiple rows with the same id and the same type? For example, two rows with id=1, type='Purchase', and either the same code, or different codes, or one having an actual code and the other having NULL for code? Also, are Purchase, Return and Exchange the only possible types? (And is type non-nullable?)

Comment: Code will always be unique and each ID will have 1 and only 1 of each type. Other types are present but I am interested only in the ones listed

Comment: Understood, but the reason I asked is that if other types are present, then a condition like `HAVING count(distinct type) = 3` will not mean exactly the three types of Purchase, Return and Exchange. See Mark's answer - he can edit it again (adding a WHERE clause for type in the enumeration of these three), but all these details are needed; you will test his solution and think it's incorrect, when in fact he was missing some relevant information which wasn't provided in the question.

Comment: Yes, the presence of additional TYPE values is a surprise since it violates assumptions I thought I saw in the original query. (But either I was misreading or the original query has been updated.)  Regardless, I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite easily.  Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select t.id,
       max(case when type = 'Purchase' then code end) as Purchase,
       max(case when type = 'Exchange' then code end) as Exchange,
       max(case when type = 'Return' then code end) as Return
from t
where 3 = (select count(distinct t2.type)
       from t t2
       where t2.id = t.id and
             t2.type in ('Purchase', 'Exchange', 'Return') and
             t2.Code is not null
      )
group by t.id;
```

This is actually simpler to express (in my opinion) using `having` without the subquery:

```
select t.id,
       max(case when type = 'Purchase' then code end) as Purchase,
       max(case when type = 'Exchange' then code end) as Exchange,
       max(case when type = 'Return' then code end) as Return
from t
group by t.id
having max(case when type = 'Purchase' then code end) is not null and
       max(case when type = 'Exchange' then code end) is not null and
       max(case when type = 'Return' then code end) is not null;
```

Many databases would allow:

```
having Purchase is not null and Exchange is not null and Return is not null
```

But Oracle doesn't allow the use of table aliases in the `having` clause.

Comment: Ok let me give this a shot. Thanks Gordon I know you helped me yesterday and I appreciate that.

Comment: I can confirm this gave the necessary data I looked for. I will play with mathguy's answer as well since efficiency is important.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE** - Based on discussion in the question comments, my previous query had a faulty assumption (which I carried over from what I thought I saw in the original query in the question); I've eliminated the bad assumption.

```
select id
     , max(case when type='Purchase' then Code end) Purchase
     , max(case when type='Return' then Code end) Return
     , max(case when type='Exchange' then Code end) Exchange
  from t
 where code is not null
   and type in ('Purchase', 'Return', 'Exchange')
 group by id
having count(distinct type) = 3
```

Comment: Seems Gordon got to about the same solution (faster and with more detail), except I kept your assumption that "if there are three types, they're the three we want" in order to simplify the HAVING clause

Comment: Yours is great too I appreciate the effort.

Comment: @Icebreaker : Won't this return id=2 as well? (Yes, it will.) This solution does not satisfy the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I will point out again (as I did in your other thread) that analytic functions will do the job much faster - they need the base table to be read just once, and there are no explicit or implicit joins.

```
   with
         test_data ( id, type, code ) as (
           select 1, 'Purchase', 'A1' from dual union all
           select 1, 'Return'  , 'B1' from dual union all
           select 1, 'Exchange', 'C1' from dual union all
           select 2, 'Purchase', 'D1' from dual union all
           select 2, 'Return'  , null from dual union all
           select 2, 'Exchange', 'F1' from dual union all
           select 3, 'Purchase', 'G1' from dual union all
           select 3, 'Return'  , 'H1' from dual union all
           select 3, 'Exchange', 'I1' from dual union all
           select 4, 'Purchase', 'J1' from dual union all
           select 4, 'Exchange', 'K1' from dual
         )
    -- end of test data; actual solution (SQL query) begins below this line
select id, purchase, return, exchange
from   ( select id, type, code
         from   ( select id, type, code,
                    count( distinct case when type in ('Purchase', 'Return', 'Exchange')
                                         then type end                         
                         ) over (partition by id)             as ct_type,
                    count( case when code is null then 1 end
                         ) over (partition by id)             as ct_code
                  from   test_data
                )
         where  ct_type = 3 and ct_code = 0
       )
pivot  ( min(code) for type in ('Purchase' as purchase, 'Return'   as return, 
                                                        'Exchange' as exchange)
       )
;
```

Output:

```
 ID PURCHASE RETURN   EXCHANGE
--- -------- -------- --------
  1 A1       B1       C1
  3 G1       H1       I1

2 rows selected.
```

Comment: I saved your answer from yesterday. I planned on sitting down and sitting with it and understanding what you were doing when I had some free time since it was the most complex of the responses. I appreciate it as well.

Comment: Compared to the solution form the other question, I would agree with what you said.  Compared to the other solutions in other answers - which also read the table just once, also have no joins, and in addition are simpler and easier to read - I would differ.  In fact I suspect by doing it as query-then-pivot this may be slower.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger - I was referring to the OP's code in the question at the top of this thread, not to the other solutions provided here. Re-read his question, including his partial attempt, and you will understand what I meant.